# Create a Conditional Constraint without a trigger

Tags: sql-server, indexing, constraints, referential-integrity

I would like to create a database constraint that would disallow all of the child records from being VOIDded.

For any given Transaction there can be many work orders. I want the database to prevent all the work orders for that transaction from being VOIDed. I do not want to use a trigger.

Table Name: Work_Order with PK Work_Order_ID
Transaction_ID is a FK to the Transaction table
VOID is a bit value

```
VOID    Work_Order_ID   Transaction_ID
-----   -------------   --------------
1       3838298         3513904
1       3839916         3513904
```

The objective is to prevent someone from accidentally VOIDing all the work orders for a transaction.

---

The following does not work... but it seems like it should.
BTW, I should have 1 work order per transaction.

```
Create FUNCTION Count_Non_Voided_Work_Orders
(
    @Transaction_ID [int]
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @Count [int]
    Select 
        @Count = ISNULL(count(*),0)
    FROM [Transaction] t
    JOIN [Work_Order] wo on wo.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID AND wo.VOID = 0
    Where t.Transaction_ID = @Transaction_ID

    RETURN @Count
END


Alter Table Work_Order
Add Constraint One_NON_Void_Must_Exist CHECK (dbo.Count_Non_Voided_Work_Orders(Transaction_ID) = 1);
```

Comment: [Limitations of CHECK Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16#limitations-of-check-constraints) has an example where a function is used to enforce an *exists* constraint. You might be able to do something similar. **Note** that the example is actually given to highlight the fact that check constraints are not enforced on deletes, so you might be able to prevent that last Void = 0 from changing to 1, but you can't use it to prevent deletion of the last Void = 0 row for a given Transaction_ID.

Comment: Is the requirement this: "For any transaction that has work orders, there must be at least one work order that is not voided"?

Comment: "I do not want to use a trigger." Why? Using a trigger is probably the best solution to this kind of problem. It can be solved using a check constraint and a UDF, but that solution has a couple of problems: First, it's harder to maintain and Second, it carries a performance penalty (TBH, I'm not sure about relatively late versions of SQL Server, but in older versions that was an actual problem for sure)

Comment: Just use triggers

Comment: Yes, Allmhuran - that is correct.

Comment: I agree with the trigger suggestion. It may be that you have heard the general advice that "triggers are bad and should be avoided", which is a good heuristic, but doesn't really apply in this case. The claim that "triggers are bad" is really a claim that "triggers are bad because they can be a source of unexpected side effects". But here there will be no unexpected side effects, the trigger would be acting as a constraint only. You can even throw a meaningful exception.